# Facebook requests: 'online friends' filter

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-requests

Is there a filter to display online friends in the Facebook request dialogue (apprequests).?
Possible filter values specified in the documentation are app_users and app_non_users.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t get the online status of friends (at least not anymore, not sure if it was ever possible), because friend permissions got removed. There is also no parameter for the dialog, so there is no way, unfortunately.